# Nginx не могу настроить ЧПУ

Tags: nginx, php, чпу

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема. Не могу никак получить ссылки вида "/hello/world/".
Если пишу

```
location {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$request_string;
}
```

тогда попытка попасть на example.ru/hello/world/ вызывает 500 Internal Server Error.
если перехожу на example.ru/?hello=world тогда все проходит без ошибок.
Сколько примеров посмотрел, ничего не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location / {
        index  index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

Это точно работает.