# Как убрать ошибку 404 не существующей страницы на nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

Bвожу в url (uk это хост) http://uk/account/register или http://uk/859498 и получаю **404 Not Found.**  На апатче настраивал (если страницы нету, то не выдает 404) Как это сделать на nginx ?
htaccess есть, но он вроде не работает в nginx

```html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRUle ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location / {
        index  index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

Это точно работает.

Источник: [Nginx не могу настроить ЧПУ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387716/nginx-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3)

Comment: Спасибо ) вышло. Знать бы что оно значит еще )